# spring hibernate @Enumerated issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We have a mysql table 'MyTable'. In this table we have 2 enum columns.

```
PayPalPayerStatus enum('verified','unverified')
PayPalAddressStatus enum('confirmed','unconfirmed')
```

I use a hibernate entity with 2 enum fields

```
private PayPalPayerStatusEnum col1;
private PayPalAddressStatusEnum col2
```

I use @Enumerated annotation on both getter methods

```
@Column(name ="paypalpayerstatus" )
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public PayPalPayerStatusEnum getPayPalPayerStatus() {
    return payPalPayerStatus;
}

public void setPayPalPayerStatus(PayPalPayerStatusEnum payPalPayerStatus) {
    this.payPalPayerStatus = payPalPayerStatus;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name ="paypaladdressstatus" )

public PayPalAddressStatusEnum getPayPalAddressStatus() {
    return payPalAddressStatus;
}
```

But!!!
If I remove @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) annotation from

```
public PayPalPayerStatusEnum getPayPalPayerStatus()
```

It begins to complain that value for column paypaladdressstatus var truncated!!!

I`ve been struggling for an hour or two, because initially I forgot to add both @Enumerated annotations, just one. So in other words, if I remove annotation from one field, it will begin to complain on absolutely another enum field!! Is it ok?

Comment: Please add more details about the errors, post complete stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this problem. Are you using hbm2ddl.auto property by any chance ?

Comment: The error *value for column paypaladdressstatus var truncated* means u r specifying the enum value larger than the size specified in DB. Try specifying `length = 50` attribute in `@Column` annotation. And one question I have, Why u hv created enum with `PayPalPayerStatus enum('verified','unverified')`, why not `enum PayPalPayerStatus(verified,unverified)` ? Also check out [JPA and Enums via @Enumerated](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html). **If your tables are auto generated by Hibernate, you can't annotate property with Enum type**.

Comment: Also make sure that the values specified in *`Java Enum` must match the values specified in `DB Enum`*.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I don't use hbm2ddl.auto. I tried to use length, no luck, such enums are historical issue of my employer`s DB, I will try to find logs there. Thanks